# Should a CompilationUnit object have the means to save itself and compile to disk?

Tags: c#, java, oop, dependency-injection

I never know how to correctly model situations when there's this data structure that I'll want to later save on disk.

For instance, I'm currently working on a small code-generator. The general idea is that I'll somewhere want to store both a class' qualified name as well as its related contents, and I'll later want to save the .java file to disk and to compile it via `javac`. It's not entirely clear that I'll want to do both actions, that is, saving to disk as .java and compiling via `javac` as just one action. I guess sometimes I might want to just write the .java file to disk without compiling.

```
class CompilationUnit {
    String qualifiedName;
    String contents;
}
```

Now, my question is on how to model this. Should I have a `CompilationUnit` that takes as arguments both an `IFileSystem` and `IJavaCompiler`, so every time I have "in my hand" a `CompilationUnit` I have everything needed to do both actions, or should I try to keep that compilation logic outside of the class, being a `CompilationUnit` just a data object?

One one hand, there's this OO belief one should keep both state and behaviour on the same object, which would favor keeping the qualified name and its contents together with the possibility of writing the compilation unit to disk and compile it.

Despite of that fact, I cannot but feel uncomfortable with the idea of having the `CompilationUnit` taking both `IFileSystem` and `IJavaCompiler` dependencies, although I it's a bit hard to explain why it is so.

My (idealist?) intuition is that a data object should be easy to instantiate, and in that view it cannot but feel awkward to have to pass in a `IFileSystem` and `IJavaCompiler` every time I want to store a qualified name and its contents together. This means that whoever is in charge of generating this data has to also have access to both `IFileSystem` and `IJavaCompiler`, which is kind of odd.

I'm not sure I've actually answered my own question or not.

This system will be tested, so a correct handling of dependencies issues is paramount.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject *Services* into *Entities* or *Value Objects*, you are most likely breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). While I don't know the details of this domain, `IFileSystem` and `IJavaCompiler` sounds a lot like *Services* to me - they're not really part of the *state* of the object, but Services it can use.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the confirmation of my suspections.